# How to dynamically change container views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicontainerview

I'm a noobie with iOS but have spent a few years with Android. I've got 3 clickable `labels` that allow for dynamic content. Here's what I mean:

[image: description]

From what I understand I need to create a `containerView` into the `MainViewController`. Then on an `event` change the content of the `containerView`. What I'm struggling with is: **Where do I keep these layouts?** Do I just have 3 `containerViews` that I then programatically hide/reveal? That seems like a waste whereas with `fragments` in Android I could just house them all in one container and replace them.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to do with these views? Are these simple(ish) views that are standalone? Or do they lead to more content? There are multiple ways to skin a cat, to use an overly graphic metaphor.

Comment: There are lots of ways you can do this.  It depends on what the contained views are.  One of the most common would be for each contained view to be a separate `UIViewController` subclass  that you place into the container view as required.  You should also look to see if a `UITabBarController` can provide what you need; on iOS consistency of UI is highly desirable and if there is a standard component that does what you want, it is good if you can use it.

Comment: Ah yes thanks @Paulw11, overlooked ViewControllers being also containers, was seeing them as just activity-like (if you're familiar with Android). Thanks for your help :)